# Using React-Intl in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, internationalization, react-intl

I develop an app which uses ReactJS on frontend and NodeJS on backend,
and I'm new to internationalization and i18n.

I want my translation JSON files used both in client and server side,
when I return an error in NodeJS I want to be able translate.

After checking npmjs and github "React-Intl" seemed as most popular tool,
on ReactJS side I used it easily.  But I couldn't find any example for NodeJS.

My app is not a universal rendered one.

Is there any example for on NodeJS
or can you suggest any other library for internationalization ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Asking for libraries belongs to https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

There is a module(https://www.npmjs.com/package/i18n) which helps.try it

Answer (score 0):

For those who wonders the my experience,

I've tried i18next library in NodeJS
and react-i18next  in ReactJS.

Now I'm able to use same library and same translation JSON files both in server and client
practically.